# Создание py-файла из под другого py-файла

Tags: python

При импортировании в другой проект возникает такая ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как создать py-файл, чтобы не возникало этого диалогового окна?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот кусочек кода:
`with open("conf.py", "w") as file: file.write('msg ' + '= ' + '"' + msg + '"')`

Comment: Какая версия питона? Если 3.x, то файл уже должен в `UTF-8` записываться. Если 2.x, то, наверное, нужно указать `encoding='UTF-8'` при открытии файла на запись.

Comment: Последняя - 3.9.6

Comment: Ну всё-равно попробуйте `encoding='UTF-8'`, если у вас `Windows`, то может быть файлы по умолчанию в кодировке `cp1251` читаются-пишутся, я точно не помню.

Comment: Само `msg` то откуда-то получается или в коде программы задаётся? Если откуда-то, то там может быть другая кодировка, наверное, не `utf-8` и нужно перекодировать.

Comment: msg задается в коде

Comment: я немного поправил вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте то, что я написал выше про `encoding`, должно помочь

Comment: спасибо помогло:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если файл записывается под ОС `Windows`, то в ней кодировка питона по умолчанию может отличаться от `utf-8` и её нужно прямо указать при записи файла:

```
with open("conf.py", "w", encoding='utf-8')
```